# Check if a string contains numbers

Tags: mysql, string, numbers

How do I check if a string in a MySQL field contains a number then delete them?

**Example table:**

```
tbl_tags
 -------------
| id | tag    |
 -------------
| 1  | hello  |
| 2  | hello2 |
| 3  | 2hello |
| 4  | hel3lo |
 -------------
```

The only way I can think of is to do each number individually and use **LIKE '%1%' OR LIKE '%2%'** etc. But there must be an easier way?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Check out the [MySQL Regex methods](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp). Something like the following should work.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE tag REGEXP '[0-9]'
```

Comment: PS: The `'` quotation marks are necessary (I've spent over an hour trying `"` without success)

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT * 
FROM clients
WHERE name REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]+$'
ORDER BY `clients`.`country_id` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

this is the answer if you're looking for strings with only digits

Comment: I think the OP is looking for strings that *contain* numbers, so you could probably just delete the `^` and `$` from the regexp