# how to find if table column value has a number in it and generate the results

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL - Check if a string contains numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269857/mysql-check-if-a-string-contains-numbers)

This is a difficult search considering it's something that seems pretty common. What I'm trying to do is do a query finding the value a column in a database table and checking if it contains any numbers and grab the results to display in a foreach loop.

The code I have now is to generate results by a particular letter:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE value LIKE '{$letter}%' ORDER BY value;"; 
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);//Codeigniter function
```

Could I do something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE value LIKE '%#%' ORDER BY value;"; 
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

I apologize if this is a super easy question. I'm a bit of a n00b. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of the `value` column - is it some int type or is it string type?

Comment: @ain: I've never heard of INT containing anything but numbers.

Comment: @Mchl Sure. And now imagine that perhaps OP wants to get all rows where the int value, when converted to str, contains particular number. I'm tring to clarify, is this is the case. But after rereading the question - it seems that this is not the case...

Comment: @ain: It's a varchar with a max of 50 characters. If that's what you mean. It's a title field for articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the answer posted here. [Check if a string contains numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269857/mysql-check-if-a-string-contains-numbers/3269865#3269865)

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE tag REGEXP '[0-9]'

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE value REGEXP '\d' ORDER BY value;";
```

this will display only records with digit in it